# eval and cats is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, grass.script, grass-7.8

I'm trying to do the r.lfp and r.accumulate examples for multiple longest flow paths, except I keep getting the "eval" or "cats" "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.". Not sure what I'm doing wrong, not used to working with GRASS I usually work on QGIS I just didn't find a way do get lfp from QGIS. Using GRASS on windows.

Here are the two codes I'm trying to put in GRASS:

For r.lfp:

```
# get nsres
eval `r.info -g map=elevation`

# delineate streams using a threshold
r.stream.extract elevation=elevation threshold=50000 stream_vector=streams

# populate stream lengths
v.db.addcolumn map=streams columns="length real"
v.to.db map=streams option=length columns=length

# create points along the streams starting from downstream
v.to.points -r input=streams output=stream_points dmax=$nsres

# find outlets (downstream-most less nsres points)
cats=`db.select -c sql="select stream_points_2.cat from stream_points_2 \
    inner join stream_points_1 on stream_points_1.cat = stream_points_2.lcat \
    where length-along > 0.5*$nsres and length-along < 1.5*$nsres"`
cats=`echo $cats | tr " " ,`
v.extract input=stream_points layer=2 cats=$cats output=stream_outlets

# create the longest flow paths for all outlets
r.lfp input=drain_directions output=lfp id_column=id outlet=stream_outlets layer=2 outlet_id_column=lcat
```

And this one for r.accumulate:

```
# set computational region
g.region raster=elevation -p

# calculate drainage directions using r.watershed
r.watershed elevation=elevation drainage=drain_directions -s -a

# get nsres
eval `r.info -g map=elevation`

# delineate streams using a threshold
r.accumulate direction=drain_directions threshold=50000 stream=streams

# populate stream lengths
v.db.addtable map=streams
v.to.db map=streams option=length columns=length

# create points along the streams starting from downstream
v.to.points -r input=streams output=stream_points dmax=$nsres

# find outlets (downstream-most less nsres points)
cats=`db.select -c sql="select stream_points_2.cat from stream_points_2 \
    inner join stream_points_1 on stream_points_1.cat = stream_points_2.lcat \
    where length-along > 0.5*$nsres and length-along < 1.5*$nsres"`
cats=`echo $cats | tr " " ,`
v.extract input=stream_points layer=2 cats=$cats output=stream_outlets

# calculate longest flow paths and delineate subwatersheds for all outlets
r.accumulate direction=drain_directions lfp=lfp id_column=id \
    outlet=stream_outlets outlet_layer=2 outlet_id_column=lcat \
    subwatershed=subwatersheds

# convert subwatersheds to vector
r.to.vect input=subwatersheds type=area output=subwatersheds
```

Not sure what I'm missing. Trying to execute this code from the GRASS Console tab maybe I need to do it from somewhere else?

Comment: The console window is a very simple command shell, supporting grass commands, and only a few basic system commands (not eval `` etc.). If you try using the actual GRASS terminal window, I believe your script should work.

Comment: @Micha it doesn't seem to be working more. Trying to put the line in the Command Prompt (C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe) but still tells me " 'eval' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.". 

I don't understand why it never works since 
eval `r.info -g map=elevation` 
has been taken straight from the example they've given for r.accumulate and r.lfp.

Comment: Ahhh, you're working in Windows. You didn't mention that in your original post. The script you posted is definitely specific to Linux. You'll have to find the Win equivalent to `eval` and the backtick usage in a Linux command shell.
Who is "they" when you mention "the example they've given"? Perhaps ask "them"??

Comment: @Micha Oh didn't know it was linux specific. When I say "they" I mean the grass doc for r.lfp and r.accumulate, these were examples I took directly from the documentation and I didn't see where it mentionned it was linux specific.
r.accumulate: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/r.accumulate.html 


r.lfp: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/r.lfp.html